# Add text or label to Custom TKinter Scrollable Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

Sorry, this is my first question!!!

I want to add a list of names in a **ScrolllableFrame** from Custom TKinter.
I am currently using **CTkLabel** for the names.

```
import customtkinter

list_names = ["Liam", "Olivia", "Noah", "Emma"]

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("1000x550")
root.title("Test")

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

other_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(master=frame, height=350, width=250, label_text="List").pack(pady=40)

for name in list_names:
        customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=other_frame, text=name).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[This is what happens when I run the code, instead of the names being in the ScrollableFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ne4c.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in you code comes from the 12th line (when you define other_frame). On the same line, you created the frame and packed it. But because you did all of that in one single line, the other_frame variable contains the return of the `.pack()` method (in this case None).

To make your code work you should replace line 12 by this:

```py
other_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(master=frame, height=350, width=250, label_text="List")
other_frame.pack(pady=40)
```

The full code is now:

```py
import customtkinter

list_names = ["Liam", "Olivia", "Noah", "Emma"]

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("1000x550")
root.title("Test")

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

other_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(master=frame, height=350, width=250, label_text="List")
other_frame.pack(pady=40)

for name in list_names:
        customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=other_frame, text=name).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope I helped you, have a nice day.

PS: you never have to excuse for asking a question ;)